# Make program make sure it has 3 instances of itself running at all times?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

There's a .NET assembly and it needs to have 3 instances running at the same time all the time how can I monitor this.

I am fairly positive it can be done by monitoring the system processes?

Comment: You can search for the process by name, but keep in mind that the name of the process isn't something that's difficult to spoof.  In your situation, this may not be a concern.  But it's something to be aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Something like this:**

```
        using System.Diagnostics;

        // ...

        string proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(proc);

        if (processes.Length != 3)
        {
            // ...
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Start the initial process and let it know that it's the master "ID1"**

To start the initial process, use a command line argument. MyProcess.exe -ID1
This instance of your process knows that it is the "master" or ID1 vs. ID2, ID3

**Step 2: Run this code periodically when the application's ProcessID is #1**

Note: You can use a timer and fire an event and handle it with the code below:

```
Imports System.Diagnostics

'Check to see if we need to spawn one or more processes
Dim ProcessCounter as integer = 0

For Each p as Process In Process.GetProcesses
    if p.NameProperty??.ToString() = "MyProcessName" then ProcessCounter += 1
Next

'Use this code to spawn new instances of the process, and assign process ID's accordingly
while processcounter < 3
   Use Process.Start() and run a new instance of your process, but pass it a command line argument -ID# where # is the # of that process (also = to ProcessCounter)
   ProcessCounter += 1
end while
```

**Notes:**

- You may want to run a "watcher" process that periodically runs the above code... you can have a windows task that runs a simple exe every minute or so that contains only the above code. You must use a "watcher" process if the master process (or the one with ID = 1 above) may terminate
- If a process has an internal ID variable that is not 1 (indicating that it is the master process that is in charge of monitoring for the existing of 3 instances), then the above code will not be run. Only one of the processes needs to do this monitoring